# How can I print a grep result with the matched word?

Tags: python, bash, grep

I have two files, "file A":

```
Adygei
Albanian
Armenia_C
Armenia_Caucasus
Armenia_EBA
Armenia_LBA
Armenia_MBA
Armenian.DG
Austria_EN_HG_LBK
Austria_EN_LBK
```

And "fileB":

```
HG01880.SG Aygei_o1.SG
HG01988.SG Adygei_o2.SG
HG02419.SG Albanian_o2.SG
HG01879.SG Albanian.SG
HG01882.SG Armenia_C.SG
HG01883.SG Armenia_C.SG
HG01885.SG Armenia_EBA.SG
HG01886.SG Armenia_EBA.SG
HG01889.SG Armenia_LBA.SG
HG01890.SG Armenia_MBA.SG
```

What I want at the end is create a new columne (doesn't matter the position of the column) with the grep word with the word that matched. Like This:

```
HG01880.SG Aygei_o1.SG Adygei
HG01988.SG Adygei_o2.SG Adygei
HG02419.SG Albanian_o2.SG Albanian 
HG01879.SG Albanian.SG Albanian
HG01882.SG Armenia_C.SG Armenia_C
HG01883.SG Armenia_C.SG Armenia_C
HG01885.SG Armenia_EBA.SG Armenia_EBA
HG01886.SG Armenia_EBA.SG Armenia_EBA
HG01889.SG Armenia_LBA.SG Armenia_LBA
HG01890.SG Armenia_MBA.SG Armenia_MBA
```

What I used to match both files in bash is `grep -wFf fileA fileB > newfileA_B.txt`. This can be both in python or bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform the `grep` search once more but this time adding the flag `-o` which only lists the matching words. Then use `paste` to add it as column (define the delimiter using the `-d` flag).

```sh
paste -d ' ' <(grep -wFf fileA fileB) <(grep -woFf fileA fileB)
```

Comment: Thanks! what exactly do '<'  here?

Comment: @HctorAlessandroLpezHernndez It's called [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html). Basically you run code and provide it to another process where it appears as a (virtual) filename. Use it like passing a filename as an argument.

Comment: Interesting command! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that:

```
for line in $(cat fileA.txt)
do
  echo "$line $(grep $line fileB.txt)"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example (probably inefficient) algorithm in Python (using strings instead of files) https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bUnFXJg0m6FvXRkPybUqWux_reaJRt1c?usp=sharing

Comment: Cool! I will save it. No one knows when could be usefull :)